# How to handle ajax response in FLUX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, flux

I'm new in FLUX and I have problem how to handle ajax in FLUX.

My situation is following :

I have file **commentAPI.js**

```
//all js files are compiled from coffescript

// fetching all comments from server
    _fetchComments: function() {
       var promise;
       promise = $.ajax({
         url: "comments/show",
         type: "GET",
         dataType: "json"
        });
        return promise.then(function(response) {
         // here should be any action ?
        }, function(error) {
         return console.log(error);
        });   }
```

Then I have **commentActions.js**

```
   fetchComments: function () {
    allcomments=commentAPI._fetchComments(); 
    return Dispatcher.dispatch({
      actionType: ActionTypes.ALL_COMMENTS,
      comments: allcomments
    });
  }
```

This code actually doesnt work because function **_fetchComments** called in **commentActions.js** return whole promise.

**What I want to do:** I would like to get response from ajax callback function and pass the result to my payload object and then dispatch it by Dispatcher in my _fetchComments() function in **commentActions.js**

How is the best way to do it? How can I get the access to the ajax callback function response ?

Answer (score 0):

You should dispatch **_fetchComments** function and when that promise is resolved, invoke the action **fetchComments**.

In the react code you should invoke the async function (i.e. **_fetchComments**).

In your example:

```
// fetching all comments from server
    _fetchComments: function() {
       var promise;
       promise = $.ajax({
         url: "comments/show",
         type: "GET",
         dataType: "json"
        });
        return promise.then(function(response) {
         // put the sync action here
         fetchComments(response)
        }, function(error) {
         return console.log(error);
        });   }
```

And don't forget to remove it from the action (i.e **fetchComments**)

Comment: If I understand well . .. I have to call action fetchComments in part of code where is promise resolved and lets say I know how to update my store and then Im not calling fetchComments method in my top-level Components but instead of this I'm calling my async method _fetchComments() ?

Comment: Something like that. You must dispatch the async action (_fetchComments) from the component, thats how it is called. [See here redux async actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#async-action-creators)